# How call route resource in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I have problem. My route definition contains:

```
route::resource('admin/settings/basic','admin\settings\BasicController');
```

but I don't know how can I call the edit action from `basiccontroller` in my `a href` link.

```
href='{{ link_to_route('admin/settings/basic/edit') }}'
```

Please give me some advice.

Comment: You don't need to, it automatically does this for you, see the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers). In basicController just create a method called edit and Laravel will call it for you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Given a route like the following:

*app/Http/routes.php*

```
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController');
```

#### Your controller could look something like this:

*app/Http/Controllers/ProfileController*

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $profile = Profile::all(); // Grab some data

    return view('profile.edit', [$profile]); // Pass some data to the Edit view
}
```

#### In the view, you might have a form for editing like so:

*resources/views/profile/edit.blade.php*

```
<?= Form::model($profile, ['route' => ['profile.update', $profile->id], 'method' => 'PUT', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) ?>
```

That form routes to **ProfileController@update**

For other routes, such as an index, it is handled all for you. You just have to make sure you return the correct view in your ProfileController@index, and hitting the route for /profile will be passed through that method

You can always refer to the documentation as well - [RESTful Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Comment: Good, but what have I put on this href? I need create link to edit action with my a href link.